# Excel Date comparison + dependency on ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with around 30k rows. within those are 6k unique IDENTIFIER numbers.

The goal is to find the last date of each IDENTIFIER, and fill in a "Null". the older entries should contain the next newest date as text. Pictures below (last one is my expected results).

How can I filter by the unique IDENTIFIER Numbers, and fullfill the cells as stated below?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Do you have MAXIFS?

Comment: I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

=IF(MAXIFS(Valid_From Col, ID Col, ID Cell)<>Valid_From Co, "NULL", MAXIFS(Valid_From Col, ID Col, ID Cell))